# Simple Paged Results control on Sun-Directory-Server/11.1.1.5.1

Tags: ldap, oracle, sun

I am confused. I am trying to run simple pager results against what I believe is Oracle 11g Directory Server. I know that an old version at some point did not support RFC 2696. Now, according to Oracle website, simple paged results control is supported.
I do not see this control as supported, and get an error telling that it is not.

I have a directory proxy server, and know that it can filter out [some] controls. This is not the problem. I have connected both directly to the server and through a proxy.

Is there a way to enable [or in the first place] to disable paged search support? If yes, how to configure Sun-Directory-Server/11.1.1.5.1 to have it enabled?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the server is the ODSEE, and it in fact does not support RFC 2696.